# After adding Splash Screen, tabbed pages do not show up?

Tags: android, xamarin, portable-class-library

After adding a splash screen using the following tutorial, the tabbed pages from my PCL do not show up in the app. It only loads the first web view and does not show all the other tabs:

https://xamarinhelp.com/creating-splash-screen-xamarin-forms/

All I have added to the project is the styles.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="splashscreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And this in the MainActivity.cs file under [Activity]:

```
Theme = "@style/splashscreen"
```

It loads the splash screen fine, the issue is that it does not show the tabs anymore and this app has web views for each tab, but it only shows the first web view.

Is it because of the theme? How do I fix it?

EDIT:

The tabbed pages are defined in the PCL class as this will be used on iOS as well.

The tabbed page comes from the PCL class:

App.cs:

```
 using System;
 using Xamarin.Forms;

 namespace WorkingWithWebview
 {
     public class App : Application // superclass new in 1.3
     {
         public App ()
        {
            var tabs = new TabbedPage ();

            //tabs.Children.Add(new DriveBuy { Title = "Drive Buy" });
            tabs.Children.Add(new UsedCS { Title = "Used Car Search" });
            tabs.Children.Add(new Classifieds { Title = "Classifieds" });
            tabs.Children.Add(new NewCS { Title = "New Car Search" });
            tabs.Children.Add(new NewCarSp { Title = "New Car Specials" });
            tabs.Children.Add(new NewCarPL { Title = "New Car Price List" 
         });
            tabs.Children.Add(new NEWS { Title = "Motoring NEWS" });
            tabs.Children.Add(new CallMeBack { Title = "Call me Back" });
            MainPage = tabs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether you are not able to see the tabbed page itself? or How it is? If you are able to see the tabbed page, then we require your tabbed page xaml inorder to understand the issue

Comment: When I don't use the splash screen, it loads all the tabs, it just shows all the tabs and it loads the first one but I can navigate to any of the other tabs. When I use the splash screen, it only loads the first page but it's not a tabbed view. I can only use the page that it shows as the other tabs do not show up. Updating the code now in the original question.

Comment: When you use splash screen, splash screen is finished after some time or it stays on that same screen.

Comment: it finishes after a few seconds and then goes into the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your styling seems to be wrong. Please follow https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/creating_a_splash_screen/ to create splashscreen